# Is it a good practice to pass via props functions to styled component file?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this code:

```
return (
    <Container>
        <Title color={status}>Some Title</Title>
        <Subtitle>
            <Icon color={status} width={`${(value / goal) * 100}%`} />
        </Subtitle>
    </Container>
)
```

Do you think it would be a better practice to put the styles logics in the styled component file?

Answer (score 0):

> I think if styles are much, this is better to put styles logics in
> another file(e.g styled component). But if styles are little can keep
> them in the same file in the upper of the definition of a component. because in this case, accessibility to them is easier.